# WPF window with custom WindowChrome maximizes differently

Tags: c#, wpf, window-chrome

I have just started to use [WindowChrome Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.windowchrome?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) on a WPF window. I have noticed that when maximizing the window, it displays differently depending on whether I use the standard Chrome or the custom Chrome. Why?

I am double clicking the top of the window to maximize in both cases there is no code behind.

Here is the XAML - to add or remove the WindowChrome I am just deleting the Style property.

```
<Window
x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:IPSurfer"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="800"
Height="450"
Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=StandardStyle}"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<!--  Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=StandardStyle}"  -->
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="StandardStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <WindowChrome
                    CaptionHeight="50"
                    GlassFrameThickness="0"
                    ResizeBorderThickness="5" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border BorderBrush="PeachPuff" BorderThickness="5">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                                <TextBlock
                                    Margin="10,8,0,0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    Text="This is the new title" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Border BorderBrush="Teal" BorderThickness="5">
        <Grid>

        </Grid>
    </Border>

</Grid>
```

[image: NormalChromeNotMaximized]
Not Maximized, Standard Chrome - notice the Teal border

[image: NormalChromeMaximized]
Maximized,Standard Chrome - this is showing the full Teal border fitting into the screen.

[image: CustomChromeNotMaximized]
With the Window styled with the WindowChrome this is what it looks like not maximized. You see a border from my WindowChrome and the Teal border.

[image: CustomChromeMaximized]
This is what it looks like maximized. My border in the Window Chrome is gone and only about half of the Teal border is there.

I also note that when I look at the Actual Width and Height of the Window when maximized the value is the same. It is just what is displayed is different.

Comment: So what is the actual question? I assume you want one look or the other?

Comment: A question mark has been added.

Comment: @McGuireV10 any other comments?

Comment: I'm using custom WindowChrome and need override the Maximize behavior. It's not looking good :/